# Managing Oracle stored procedures in go

Tags: oracle, go

I am trying to load 300 million records from the stored procedure cursor. (Gordor + sql)
"database/sql" + "github.com/godror/godror"

Making sql rows

```
func (o *OracleDb) OpenCursorTX(tx *sql.Tx, sqlStmt string) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    var cur driver.Rows
    ctx := context.Background()
    stmt, err := tx.PrepareContext(ctx, sqlStmt)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("error parsing cursor %s: %s", sqlStmt, err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    
    if _, err := stmt.ExecContext(ctx, sql.Out{Dest: &cur}, godror.PrefetchCount(100000), godror.FetchArraySize(100000)); err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("error exec cursor %s: %s", sqlStmt, err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    rows, err := godror.WrapRows(ctx, tx, cur)
    
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("error cursor wrap rows %s: %s", sqlStmt, err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := stmt.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return rows, nil
}
```

Reading rows in code

```
rows, err := l.oracleDb.OpenCursorTX(tx, "begin drs_router_read.get_rate_b_groups(po_rate_b_groups => :po_rate_b_groups); end;")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var rbg domain.RmsGroupHist
    var gwgrId, direction int
    var dialCode, key, rbgDBegin, rbgDEnd string
    rbgMap := make(map[string][]domain.RmsGroupHist)
i:=0
for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&gwgrId, &direction, &dialCode, &rbg.RmsgId, &rbgDBegin, &rbgDEnd); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("error scan db rows loadRateBGroups %v", err)
        }
        rbg.DBegin = util.StrToInt64(rbgDBegin)
        rbg.DEnd = util.StrToInt64(rbgDEnd)
        key = domain.RBObjectKey + ":" + strconv.Itoa(gwgrId) + ":" + strconv.Itoa(direction) + ":" + dialCode
        rbgMap[key] = append(rbgMap[key], rbg)
        i++
        if i%100000 == 0 {
            logrus.Infof("rows %d\n", i)
        }
    }
```

rows.Next() hangs for 17 minutes after that len(rbgMap) = 0

I think I'm missing something, it works fine on 9 million.

Comment: I found the problem, the cursor was sorting and we waited 17 minutes for the first line and then ran out of TEMP on the base. But why didn't we know about it in any way, no rows.Next() generates errors

Comment: You can report issues on the GitHub repo.